# Rails Failure ---expected +++ actual @@ -1 +1 @@

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I am working on the Michael Hartl tutorial. When running my test, I get the following failure:

```
1) Failure:
SessionsHelperTest#test_current_user_returns_right_user_when_session_is_nil
 [/home.../myapplication/test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb:11]:
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1 +1 @@
-#<User id:... >
+nil
```

Could anyone help make sense of this failure especially the following:

```
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1 +1 @@
```

Is there any official documentation from rails that gives guidance on those find of failure message? I have not found any. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know this tutorial and I don't know almost nothing of test but I think you have a error in your app. You get a `nil` output `+nil` and the expected output is a User element `-#<User id:... >`

Maybe you have wrong `User.where` clause

If you put more info I can try help more

Comment: I just figured it out. The following page give an example of this "--- expected/+++ actual" statement http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html (it is basically a straightforward discrepancy between what you test expect and what it actually returns). This issue was coming from the helpers method that was tested.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had `def current_user` twice in `app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb` and one of them was outdated.